# How can I setup tab size in Sublime text 2 for each file type?

Tags: sublimetext2

For example, in *.asm files I need a tab size that equals 20 spaces, and in *.cpp files - 2 spaces.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Open a `.asm` file in Sublime Text.

Then edit syntax specific settings with menu `Preferences -> Settings - More -> Syntax Specific - User`:

```
{
    "tab_size": 20
}
```

You can do the same with any other file type.

Comment: It is not quite right. I did what you wrote and now these settings are for all "plain text" file types such as *.asm, *.rc, *.inc, ... Maybe there are somthing like -> "File type" Specific - User

Comment: This is because `.asm` files are not supported "natively" by Sublime Text, so it sets it as a plain text file. Sorry, I didn't remember this...

Try to import this Textmate bundle in your package directory and try again: https://github.com/13xforever/x86-assembly-textmate-bundle

Comment: I've made a simple sytax definition for .asm files. Now it works fine. Thanks

Comment: syntax doesn't means file type; i'm using PHP syntax in .html file (which I use it as template file), but I just want to use different tab in HTML file. What should I do?

Comment: Process is still the same (open specific file type), but the ST3 menu has changed now, `Settings - More` is gone.  It is now just `Settings - Syntax Specific` :)